# Exception in create user on ejabberd16.09：Denied by ACL

Tags: android, xmpp, ejabberd, smack

I installed the ejabberd16.09 in the Linux. An when I create a new user in Android , get these codes:

```
<iq from='hsoft.com' to='kfb@hsoft.com/Smack' id='T61DB-59' type='error'>        
    <query xmlns='jabber:iq:register'><username>ddk</username>
    <password>123456</password><registered/></query><error code='403' type='auth'>
    <forbidden xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas'/><text xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas'>
    Denied by ACL</text></error></iq>
```

And my file 'conf/ejabberd.yml' in the Linux :

```
  ## To disable in-band registration, replace 'allow' with 'deny'.
  register:
    - allow 
  ## Only allow to register from localhost
  trusted_network:
    - allow
  ## Do not establish S2S connections with bad servers
  ## s2s:
  ##   - deny:
  ##     - ip: "XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX/32"
  ##   - deny:
  ##     - ip: "XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX/32"
  ##   - allow
```

My Android code :

```
    private void XmppRegister(){
        AccountManager account = AccountManager.getInstance(con);
        account.sensitiveOperationOverInsecureConnection(true);
        try {
            account.createAccount("ddk".toLowerCase(), "123456");
            Log.d("PushTest", "register successfully");
        } catch (SmackException.NoResponseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (XMPPException.XMPPErrorException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SmackException.NotConnectedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Please help me! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You have to add

```
AccountManager.getInstance(connection)
                .sensitiveOperationOverInsecureConnection(true);
```

to disable your ACL while you are registering a new user, then switch back to default settings:

```
AccountManager.getInstance(connection)
                .sensitiveOperationOverInsecureConnection(false);
```

Comment: Thank you! But I had added it to my code, and still "Denied by ACL". I don't kown the resson.